# directx multithreading tutorial/sample codes

Tags: directx

I am new to DirectX.

Where can I get tutorials and sample codes for multi threading using directx and C++?

I need to findout the distance transform of an image using multi threading.

Or could you please give me an example of finding the average of 100 numbers using directx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best source for DirectX samples tends to be the DirectX SDK, which you can find [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6812). There are quite a few tutorials around, some in the SDK, some [here](http://www.directxtutorial.com/) and [here](http://www.gametutorials.com/gtstore/c-5-directx.aspx).

Multithreading with DirectX (I assume you mean D3D in specific) just requires being careful with your objects and using the multithread hint when creating the D3D object. Some tips on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147224%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and a discussion on how to over [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/364337-multithreaded-directx/).

The code will look something like:

```
HRESULT hr = pD3DObject->CreateDevice
(
    D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd, 
    D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED, &presentParams, &pD3DDevice
);
```

After that, finding the distance transform depends on how you're handling that. I'm not entirely sure what you want to do (if you comment with details I'll see if I can edit something more in).

To generate the average of numbers, I wouldn't actually recommend using DirectX. Regular code should be able to handle that, and the work and overhead of using D3D to average 100 numbers seems rather inefficient.

Comment: Note the latest version of the legacy DirectX SDK samples are available on [MSDN Code Gallery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

MSDN: [DirectX Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/aa937781).